# Create an xml drawable resource with this shape

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

Can any one help me with the code to draw this shape in xml

Comment: Try to draw using Inkscape and convert from SVG into XML in Android studio

Comment: Is it possible to do without svg? The design is something like that if we cut this image in two parts horizontally the first half comes in one text view and second half comes in other textview placed below it @DeadStar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own shape using https://editor.method.ac/ and save as a Image, so you can get a SVG file as a output.

After creating your shape as a SVG, you can add this SVG as a Vector Asset in you android app drawable folder from `app->New->Vector Asset`

In opened dialog for vector asset set the below detail and create xml for svg.

```
Asset Type : Local file
Name : your desired xml file name
Path : SVG file path
```

So now you can use this xml in your code.